# D3 colour gradient not forming mathematical circle around centre of area

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, radial-gradients

I am trying to do a radial area plot with a colour gradient to reflect this. However the gradient does not appear to ever want to sit perfectly in line / at the correct side  with the circle (see image below).

I have tried constraining the width and hight of the svg so that they are equal, but with no avail.Every refresh (with random data), the central ring for the gradient will shift and warp into a different shape, but never lie on the mean line where it should be.

[image]

I have ensured that the svg is square

```
 var width = window.innerWidth ,   height = window.innerHeight;

  width = height =   d3.min([width,height])

  var data = d3.range(0,100).map(d=>Math.random())
```

Given the gradient the following properties

```
 var linearGradient = defs.append("radialGradient")
.attr("id", "rad-gradient")
.attr("cx", "50%")    //The x-center of the gradient, same as a typical SVG circle
.attr("cy", "50%")    //The y-center of the gradient
.style("r", "50%");
```

and my area mathematically as

```
var area = d3.area()
 .x1(function(d,i) { return width/2+Math.cos(i\*angle)*(h(d)) })     .x0(function(d,i) { return > width/2+Math.cos(i\*angle)*(h(mean)) })    .y0(function(d,i) {> return height/2+Math.sin(i\*angle)*(h(mean)) })    .y1(function(d,i) { return height/2+Math.sin(i\*angle)*(h(d)) })
```

And appended the created gradient to the svg path

```
svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style("fill", "url(#rad-gradient)")
```

Comment: May be you should close your chart path. Use `.interpolate("basis-closed")` for example

Comment: I am using the cardinal closed interpolation, although since this effect exists with and without it, It was not given in the pseudo code. I came up with a simple solution using clip paths which seems to work (I believe it was fitting an ellipsoid as the net path width/height ratios were not square).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in creating a circle and filling it with the correct gradient. This ensures that the radial gradient will always be centered around the origin. 
[image]

You can then use clipPath to extract only the path you wish to use from the circle. After a little fiddling to align the gradient radius, we get the desired effect.

```
// previous definition for area path appended as a clip path
clip = defs.append("clipPath")
  .attr('id','clip')
  .append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area)

//extracting this path from a circle with the desired gradient
svg.append("circle")

  .attr("cx", width/2)
  .attr("cy", height/2)
        .attr("r", rmax)
        .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
      .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient)")
```

[image: clipped path from circle]